# Turn XML into a Multiline String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, string, parsing

I have a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<productenv:Envelope>
    <productenv:Body>
        <products>
            <productName>TestProduct</productName>
            <productPrice>50.00</productPrice>
        </products>
    </productenv:Body>
</productenv:Envelope>
```

I am receiving this file from an external server using PHP. The XML is then passed to a javascript file. Here is what the javascript does with the variable that XML is stored in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var result = "<?php echo $result; ?>"; // $result is the variable that sorts the xml file
  console.log(result);
</script>
```

When I run the code I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number. This is because the XML is turned into a string, but the double quotes that surround the 1.0 and UTF-8 are messing up the file.

Is there any way I could make the XML a multiline string that I could parse?

Comment: If you are trying to read the XML and act up it, try here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Sure, thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `$result` string doesn't contain any backtick characters, you can try using [javascript's template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var result = `<?php echo $result; ?>`; // $result is the variable that sorts the xml file
  console.log(result);
</script>
```